# ambiguous javascript output

Tags: javascript, parameters, casting, arguments

This is the code below to convert hours and minutes that is time into decimal number to calculate earnings on per hour basis.
Input: hours =  12; minutes = 30
Output: 120.50
But I want output as 12.50
I could do that by manipulating decimal point in output but that won't correct my logic.
I cannot guess what's going on . Please help

```
var $hoursInput     = $('.js-hours-input');
var $minutesInput   = $('.js-minutes-input');
var $decimalOutput  = $('.js-converted-hours');
var $errorsOutput   = $('.js-errors');

function convert(){

  let hours = parseInt($hoursInput.val());
  let minutes = parseInt($minutesInput.val());
  let total;

    if (hours == NaN || hours > 23 || hours < 0){
        $errorsOutput.html('Hours must be an integer from 0 to 23!');
    }
    else if (minutes == NaN || minutes > 59 || minutes < 0){
        $errorsOutput.html('Minutes must be in range 0 to 59');
    }
    else{
    total = hours + (minutes/60).toFixed(2);
        $decimalOutput.html(total);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $button = $('.conversion-button');

  $button.on('click', convert);

});
```

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns a string, so that `+` is string concatenation not addition.

Comment: Thanks dude it was so trivial

Comment: NaN is never `==` to any other value, even NaN so `hours == NaN` will be false for all possible values of *hours*. You might try `isNaN(hours)`.